# Paperclip: Isn't creating the thumb folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using the paperclip gem (3.0.4) which suddenly stopped working as it is no longer creating the thumb folder, only original. Because of this my code can't find the image that was uploaded and errors out.

In my model I have:

```
has_attached_file :image,
    :whiny => false,
      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
      :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
      :styles => { :thumb => "150x100#" }
```

This code hasn't changed, and when I attempt to render my view I get the following error:

```
/public/system/images/52/thumb/2011-03-16_07-49-52_412.jpg not found
```

Looking in my file system I have, `/public/system/images/52/original/2011-03-16_07-49-52_412.jpg`

Could this be an issue with ImageMagick?

Any idea what is causing this and how to resolve it to ensure the thumb folder is being created?  Thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: `original` is the default style where paperclip stores the original image. if you upload a new image, it's supposed to create both folders, thumb and original. Is it not?

Comment: no, its only creating original.  thumb isn't being created and that is what my code is looking for.